# NHibernate IsInsensitiveLike treats strings as case sensitive

Tags: c#, database, nhibernate

Hi I have to following code

```
CurrentSession.QueryOver<Entity>()
.WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.Name).IsInsensitiveLike(filterValue,MatchMode.Anywhere)
.List()
```

As far as I know the comparision should be case insensitive, however if the name is "Country" the word "country" won't return any matches.

What is wrong in this code expression?

Thanks,

Comment: What DB are you using? SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

There is too few information but in general - this should *(almost must)* work. This feature is implemented by

[InsensitiveLikeExpression.cs](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Criterion/InsensitiveLikeExpression.cs#L62)

Here is the snippet

```
public override SqlString ToSqlString(ICriteria criteria
  , ICriteriaQuery criteriaQuery, IDictionary<string, IFilter> enabledFilters)
{
    //TODO: add default capacity
    SqlStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlStringBuilder();
    SqlString[] columnNames =
        CriterionUtil.GetColumnNames(propertyName, projection
                                    , criteriaQuery, criteria, enabledFilters);

    if (columnNames.Length != 1)
    {
        throw new HibernateException("insensitive like may only " +
            " be used with single-column properties");
    }

    if (criteriaQuery.Factory.Dialect is PostgreSQLDialect)
    {
        sqlBuilder.Add(columnNames[0]);
        sqlBuilder.Add(" ilike ");
    }
    else
    {
        sqlBuilder.Add(criteriaQuery.Factory.Dialect.LowercaseFunction)
            .Add("(")
            .Add(columnNames[0])
            .Add(")")
            .Add(" like ");
    }

    sqlBuilder.Add(criteriaQuery.NewQueryParameter(
        GetParameterTypedValue(criteria, criteriaQuery)).Single());

    return sqlBuilder.ToSqlString();
}
```

Which means, that if we use Postgre dialect - **`ilike`** is used. For any other case we should see *(example realted to SQL Server and its dialect)*

```
...
WHERE lower(this_.Name) like @p0'
,N'@p0 nvarchar(4000)'
,@p0=N'%country%'
```

Also Check the calling side [QueryOverRestrictionBuilder.cs](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Criterion/Lambda/QueryOverRestrictionBuilder.cs#L132):

```
/// <summary>
/// A case-insensitive "like", similar to Postgres "ilike" operator
/// </summary>
public TReturn IsInsensitiveLike(object value)
```

Comment: I'll add (your code doesn't show) that the parameter is correctly (if we can call "correctly" the butchering of using `ToLower`, and of doing it even for PostgreSql where it isn't needed) converted to ToLower in the `GetParameterTypedValue`