# How can I do case insensitive and concatenated field searches using nhibernate / linq?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have an asp.net-mvc website that uses Fluent Nhibernate Linq / SQL Server.  I have a textbox where someone can enter a name and that generate the following query that I am using now to search my Person table:

```
 return Session.Query<Person>()
          .Where(r => (r.LastName.Contains(s) || r.FirstName.Contains(s)));
```

This works as expected in terms of translating to a "SQL like query"

```
 Select * from Person where FirstName like '%%' or LastName like '%%'
```

but I have 2 new requirements that I am not sure that nhibernate linq supports.

1. In some cases people are entering the name in upper or lower case so I want to be able to do a case insensitive search.
2. Since it's a single textbox, in some cases people type in both the first and last name (something like "Smith, Joe" and that fails to find a result given that overall string doesn't exist in either the first or last name fields.  Besides breaking the UI up into separate fields (which I can't do for some other reasons) is there any suggestion on how I could support the query to include the following combination of user's search string

   - [First] [Last]
   - [Last], [First]

in the above search code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve issue with mixed upper/lower, we can just convert both sides into `.ToLower()`

```
return Session.Query<Person>()
      .Where(r => (r.LastName.ToLower().Contains(s.ToLower()) 
                || r.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(s.ToLower())));
```

Check this link for more details how the NHibernate native **InsensitiveLikeExpression.cs** is working *(for almost every dialect **it is doing the same**)* :

- [NHibernate IsInsensitiveLike treats strings as case sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30106436/1679310)

The second part, here is some super simple algorithm *(if it is one at all)*

```
var first = searched.Split(' ')[0].ToLower();
var last = searched.Split(' ')[1].ToLower();

var emps = session.Query<Person>()
        .Where(e =>
            (e.FirstName.ToLower().StartsWith(first)
             && e.LastName.ToLower().StartsWith(last))
            ||
            (e.FirstName.ToLower().StartsWith(last)
             && e.LastName.ToLower().StartsWith(first))
        )
```

Very similar solution could be used *(and I do)* for combobox searching... Where "Ra Ko" will also find Radim Kohler...

Answer (score 0):

Your first point-

> 1). In some cases people are entering the name in upper or lower case
>   so I want to be able to do a case insensitive search.

Answer is already given by Radim Köhler - that convert both sides into `.ToLower()`

Now for your second point, below might be useful.

```
return session.Query<Person>()
       .Where(e =>
            ((e.FirstName.ToLower() + " " + e.LastName.ToLower()).Contains(s))
            ||
            ((e.LastName.ToLower() + ", " + e.FirstName.ToLower()).Contains(s))
        )
```

There might be any syntax error as i have not tested in VS.